# Format date with javaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello i am geting JSON response from web service, with date in this format

```
20140424T00:00:00
```

Is it posible to format this date something like this

`24.04.2014` in euro format with javaScript

I try to use functions new Date() and toLocaleString() but not success with this format? Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: it will be easier to use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: i will try to avoid including more libraries into my project

Comment: maybe to trim left part and then use some function?

Comment: found a function toJSON()

Comment: need something to decode this from json

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vp6ybL3c/2/

Comment: thank mate seems to work pls submit answer so i could vote up and select as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a simple format function

```
function formatDate(date){
    return date.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*/, '$3.$2.$1')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vp6ybL3c/)

Comment: is it possible to upgrade this code to work with this format 2014-04-24T00:00:00"

Comment: @VladimirStus do you want to support both these formats or only one

Comment: is some mistcke in JSON response it should be real JSON format 2014-04-24T00:00:00 with dashes - i think now i can use new Date function

Comment: tnx your are the best!